# If A has empty interior then its closure is empty

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Suppose A has empty interior. Suppose, for a contradiction, that its closure, $A'$, is not empty. Then, WLOG, we can assume that there exists some nonempty open set $U$, and point $x$, such that $U \cap A \triangleq \{x\}$. $x$ must be on the boundary of $A$, and in the interior of $U$. As such, there remains a region of overlap between the interior of $U$ and $A$. Thus $A$ contains (at least one) nonempty open ball. Thus $A$ has nonempty interior. A contradiction.

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't the closure of $A$ always contains $A$?

Comment: Correct, the closure will always contain $A$ as @ArcticChar noted.  This makes the problem trivial as long as $A$ is not empty.  Do you mean for $A'$ to be the set of limit points of $A$, not the closure?

Comment: $\{0\}$ has empty interior, and is closed.

Comment: Have you considered the set of rational numbers $\mathbb Q$? What is it's interior and what is it's closure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $A=\mathbb Z$ for instance and $U=(-\frac 12,\frac 12)$.

$U\cap A=\{0\}$ as you stated but that's all. Your implication "there remains a region of overlap between the interior of $U$ and $A$" is true but this region is just $\{0\}$, it doesn't extend further to an open ball.